# How to manipulate php time data and get a result in hour:minute format

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a program where it calculates start hour and finish hour and gets the time in between to see how many hours have been worked (the start and stop variables are replaced by time values from a database in the real code)

Here is an example:

```
$start = "11:15:35"
$stop = "17:30:13"


$start2 = date( 'G:i' ,strtotime($start) );
$stop2 = date( 'G:i' ,strtotime($stop) );

echo $stop2 ."<br>". $start2;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $stop2 - $start2;
```

I need the code to output something like 6.25 or 6h and 15min, currently it is only doing hours and outputting just a 6.

i have tried 
`$stop2[1] & start2[1]`

and changing around the 'G:i' bit with various other letters from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Sorry if this is a simple question, any answers appreciated!

Edit: misspelt minute

Comment: What if this wraps over midnight? Times without dates are pretty difficult to deal with. Remember `date` is dealing with date/datetime values, not arbitrary time *intervals*.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I have a date column in the MySQL table and probably going to add functionality to allow going over midnight in future or some way to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$hour_one = "17:30:13";
$hour_two = "11:15:35";

$h =  strtotime($hour_one);
$h2 = strtotime($hour_two);

$minute = date("i", $h2);
$second = date("s", $h2);
$hour = date("H", $h2);

$convert = strtotime("-$minute minutes", $h);
$convert = strtotime("-$second seconds", $convert);
$convert = strtotime("-$hour hours", $convert);
$new_time = date('H:i:s', $convert);

echo $new_time;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to get the difference between time as follows

```
    $a = new DateTime('11:15:35');
    $b = new DateTime('17:30:13');
    $interval = $a->diff($b);

    echo $interval->format("%H:%i:%S");
```